# Crosswalk WebView doesn't Pause when Loaded anything on webview

Tags: cordova, crosswalk

I'm using crosswalk webview in cordova project. but it will doen't pause when load any app or anything.

I have added plugin of crosswalk:
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

after the plugin my config.xml look below:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<preference name="webView" value="org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkWebViewEngine" />
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="23+" />
<preference name="xwalkLiteVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
<preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

Comment: If the community is to help you with this, you really need to add a concrete example of what you have tried that didn't work, please.

Comment: but in cordova just need to add its thats it plugin.i think !

Comment: So show the community exactly how you have installed and configured it - at present there is nothing for anyone to go on.

Comment: i have edited my question @MandyShaw

Comment: Hopefully someone will be able to help you now.

Comment: ok,thanks @MandyShaw